# Loader not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am working with an ajax loader gif that I am trying to show when a user clicks a button (while waiting for the response the gif is shown).

Everything works fine in Chrome and FireFox however when it comes to testing on IE it breaks.

**Html**

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="ShowLoading()"/>

 <div id="blockScreen" class="blockScreen" style="display:none; width:100%; text-align:center;" >&nbsp;</div>
 <img src="Images/ajax_loader.gif" style="display: none;"/>
```

**javScript**

```
  function ShowLoading() {

       var divBg = document.getElementById('blockScreen');
       var divLoad = document.createElement('div');
       var img = document.createElement('img');

       img.src = 'Images/ajax_loader.gif';
       img.height = 100;
       img.width = 100;
       divLoad.setAttribute("class", "blockScreenLoader");
       divLoad.appendChild(img);

       divBg.appendChild(divLoad);


       if (document.getElementById('MainContent_gridDiv') != null) {
           document.getElementById('MainContent_gridDiv').style.display = 'none';

       }

       document.getElementById('blockScreen').style.display = 'block';

   }
```

**Error**

> Error: The value of the property 'ShowLoading' is null or undefined,
>   not a Function object

I have tried stripping the code down to the bare minimum however still the error persists. Why is this happening in IE?

Comment: Which version of IE is broken?

Comment: try by placing semicolon at end of function and are you sure Images not images

Comment: IE 11, same problem in 10 also.

Comment: Are you using outside of the function the name "ShowLoading" as a variable? The error message explains that it doesn't recognize "ShowLoading" as a function.

Comment: Not any jQuery code `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the script block at the bottom of your html and this is means that the function does not exist when the onclick attribute is parsed. Here is an example that works in  IE (tested with IE11) http://jsfiddle.net/T5aEn/

Note that if you change the location if the script block to something like "ondomready" then you get the undefined function error.

```
<head>
    <script>
    function ShowLoading() {
        ...
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="ShowLoading()"/>

     <div id="blockScreen" class="blockScreen" style="display:none; width:100%; text-align:center;" >&nbsp;</div>
     <img src="Images/ajax_loader.gif" style="display: none;"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand your answer, currently my page is using a master page which I believe could be offsetting some of my javascript, I am going to make an independent aspx page not using a master page (as it is a one page app anyway, and reshuffle the code. If that works I will definitely mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with IE 11 is that you have to add img object to the page before assigning the src attribute,

Example

This fails in IE 11

```
var img = New Image()
img.src = 'test.gif'    
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Try

```
var img = New Image();
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = 'test.gif'
```